# error running iphython : cannot open:libgfortran.so.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, gcc, scipy, archlinux

I am getting the following error when I try to run my Jupyter notebook:

```
<ipython-input-1-5a76ca40a88e> in <module>()
      3 import random
      4 import numpy as np
----> 5 from cs231n.data_utils import load_CIFAR10
      6 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      7 

/home/rashik/CS231n/assignment1/cs231n/data_utils.py in <module>()
      4 import numpy as np
      5 import os
----> 6 from scipy.misc import imread
      7 import platform
      8 

/home/rashik/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/misc/__init__.py in <module>()
     47 from .common import *
     48 from numpy import who, source, info as _info
---> 49 from scipy.special import comb, factorial, factorial2, factorialk
     50 
     51 import sys

/home/rashik/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py in <module>()
    599 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    600 
--> 601 from ._ufuncs import *
    602 
    603 from .basic import *

ImportError: libgfortran.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am using Arch linux and have gcc 8.1.1 20180531 installed. I tried downgrading to older versions but the error remained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed issue by upgrading scipy and numpy.

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked, and I couldn't find a solution until I reached this page. Exact command: `pip install --upgrade scipy`